# Cannot search in all columns of differing types

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

This *looks* like an old question but it's actually not. I couldn't find an answer on SO or elsewhere.

I have this table:

```
n (number) | s (varchar2)
-------------------------
200        | some string
201        | some other string
```

I can *cast* the number `n` to a string and select it without problems like so:

```
SELECT n FROM t;
SELECT TO_CHAR(n) FROM t;
```

But I need to search in all columns for a string value. What I've tried (and it works generally, meaning the DB is an *11g*) is `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT * FROM t UNPIVOT (anywhere FOR col IN (...));
```

However, what does **NOT** work is mixing data types (numbers and character-based types such as `varchar2`). What I get is:

> ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

That's ok, I understand this and the solution is obvious. Cast numbers to characters. But that doesn't work either. For the immediate solution:

```
SELECT * FROM t UNPIVOT (anywhere FOR col IN (s, TO_CHAR(n)));
                                                        ^
```

I get this unexpected error:

> ORA-00917: missing comma

The problem here is that `TO_CHAR` is not interpreted as a function at all, it is thought to be a column name like `s` or `n`.

So, how can I use `UNPIVOT` with mixed data types *or* how can I cast all columns to `varchar2` *or* how else can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT to_char(n) as n, s FROM t) 
UNPIVOT (anywhere FOR col IN (...));
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I don't know the column list because it's not hard-coded, so I don't know what is a number and what is not. Can I just cast all columns with `TO_CHAR()`, dates included? I'll do a quick test and be back soon :)

Comment: It's a bit more complex because of the *meta*-nature of the query but by pulling the types prior to constructing the query it's feasible, I've already fixed a simplified case and am confident it'll work in the general case, too. Thanks!